# Create random number which is not in array

Tags: java

i have a number of switch cases which should be random selected, but only each switch case once. I made a random generator and an array for adding the cases, but im stuck since i am not that good in code.
Here is what i currently have

```
 public void showRandomButton() {
        //Generate Random Numbers
        final int min = 0;
        final int max = 13;  //n-no of random events
        Random g=new Random();
        int random = g.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
        //Random number 0(inclusive)-9(inclusive)

        while(Arrays.asList(list).contains( random )) {
            int numb = g.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
            random = numb;

        }
        switch(random){
            case 1:
                mbutton1.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                mbuttonStart.setVisibility( View.GONE );
                break;
            case 2:
                mbutton2.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                mbuttonStart.setVisibility( View.GONE );
                break;
                //Function 2 break;
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out :

```
int min = 0;
int max = 13;  
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for(int i = min; i <max;)
{
int rand = ((int)(Math.random() * max)) + 1;
if(!list.contains(rand))
{
    list.add(rand); // it will be added only if not in list
    i++;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the `switch/case` into the loop, otherwise it just go trought the switch once after the loop.

Comment: the function is activated after a button is pressed, so it should work this way ?